# WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode is not working

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-rest

In WCF REST API I would like to set own StatusCode for some reason -

```
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden (or any other statuscode)
```

it doesn't work at all as in the client end : -

```
 using (HttpWebResponse restResponse = (HttpWebResponse)restRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                if (restResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {


                    retVal = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}, Description : {1}", restResponse.StatusCode, restResponse.StatusDescription);
                    return retVal;
                }

                using (var st = restResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st);
                    retVal = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    return retVal;
                }
            }
```

but here the restResponse.StatusCode is always HttpStatusCode.OK.

May I know the reason? What is wrong here?

**Addition to it: -**

I tried using following in Rest Service Method --

```
throw new WebFaultException<string>(<...Your message....>, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden );
```

but the issue with this approach is that at client end.....it makes the code to come out of

```
Try
{

    using (HttpWebResponse restResponse = (HttpWebResponse)restRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (restResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {


                        retVal = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}, Description : {1}", restResponse.StatusCode, restResponse.StatusDescription);
                        return retVal;
                    }

                    using (var st = restResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st);
                        retVal = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        return retVal;
                    }
                }
}
catch
{
    //it comes here when using "throw new WebFaultException...." 
}
```

there is no point to use --

```
retVal = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}, Description : {1}", restResponse.StatusCode, restResponse.StatusDescription);
return retVal;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In WCF Rest API you can use this

```
throw new WebFaultException<string>(<...Your message....>, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden );
```

Comment: @tdelpine, I tried to do that even, but the issue is that in this case client code comes out of "using (HttpWebResponse restResponse = (HttpWebResponse)restRequest.GetResponse())" statement and goes to the error page which I don't want.

Comment: What you want that client doing ??? turn the customErrors to off in system.web section in the web.config